# Kony Camera Snapshot Delay

Tags: camera, snapshot, delayed-execution, ios-camera, temenos-quantum

I am trying to set a 5 second snapshot delay on the Camera function in Kony Visualizer.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *`kony.timer.schedule*` API for Camera Snapshot delay.

Basically, you can use this API when you want to execute a function after a specified interval of time. i.e, for example, to run a specific function after a specific time and/or for every 15 seconds.

Syntax:
*`kony.timer.schedule(timerid,funcObj,interval,repeat)`*

where

- timerid - unique ID for timer (string)
- funcObj - function that needs to be executed (function)
- interval - specifies the time in seconds after which the function needs to be executed(number)
- repeat - to repeat function or not (boolean)

So, You just need to call this timer function on "OnCapture" Action for Camera Widget.

Read Kony documents for reference
http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/viz_api_dev_guide/content/kony.timer_functions.htm